# Is it possible to bi-directionally route a 4G signal using a connected set of antennas only?

Tags: signal

Is it possible to route a 4G signal from inside a room to just outside the room without using a powered booster if the signal right outside the room is good?

I'm assuming there is lot of interference within the apartment itself (too many walls?) and the cell closest tower is located somewhere far to the left hand side (refer to room layout in images) of my room.

Room config and current situation:

[image: Room config and current situation]

I don't get any better 4G signals in the other rooms either.

Would the following antenna setup work?
[image: Anteena setup]

[Yagi antenna & inner patch panel antenna reference](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08CKSSLHP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Note: The inner patch panel antenna doesn't look suitable for higher (~2k) 4G frequencies since the description reads 698 to 700 MHz. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You've read the reviews, right?

Comment: @Finbarr I did, yes, but thought it would be possible that the buyers had installed it wrongly. But the proposed answer suggests that's not the case and bi-directional amplifiers are important.

Answer (score 1):

No this will not work for a very good and easy to understand reason. The Yagi and the patch antennas, like any other antenna, have their specific efficiencies and associated losses. So your system proposed based on the seller's claims, assumes there are no losses going from the Yagi to the patch. (By losses I mean a reduction in electrical signal due to conductor resistances and other imperfections in the cables etc.) Then it is also assumed that efficiency to capture and to transmit radio signals somehow, are perfect 100%. This is never the case, even for some of the best antennas your money can buy ! There are also cable losses and potential impedance mismatches that will render the system useless without overcoming with amplifier gain ! You would need bi-directional amplifiers to get something out of this, a lot more costly and beyond the scope of what the buyer would want for the low price ... Don't waste your money ...